# Find the shortest s-t trail(edge disjoint path) in a graph with negative weight edges

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness, shortest-path

A walk in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which joins a sequence of vertices. A trail is a walk in which all edges are distinct. Note that a trial may visit a vertex multiple times as long as no edge is revisited.

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ where the weight of each edge may be negative. Let $s,t \in V$ be our source and destination vertices, respectively. We are asked to find the shortest $s-t$ trail in $G$.

This problem seems harder than the elementary shortest path problem. But I failed to reduce it to this problem. I've also tried to do reductions from Hamiltonian cycle or feedback arc set, however I failed again. Could you please shed some light upon it?

Comment: Is the "longest edge-disjoint path" problem knowing to be NP-hard?  If so, the same logic as the ["shortest vertex-disjoint path with negative cycles" problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462) should work

Comment: I think what you are talking about are "trails", not "trials". With the right word, you can find the answer on this site. See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20682/

Comment: Can't you reduce Hamiltonian Path/Cycle? Take an unweighted graph $G$ and to each vertex $v$ add a dummy vertex $v'$ connected only to $v$ via large negative length edges in both directions.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri A vertex in $G$ can be revisited via a cycle containing it. So even if $G$ has no Hamiltonian cycle,  we can visit all vertices in $G'$ by a trail, thus visiting all dummy cycles.

Comment: @Mengfan Ma Yes, that is true but if there is a Hamitonian cycle the cost would be n - 2nW where W is the weight of the dummy edges. If there is no Hamilton Cycle it will necessarily have include more unit weight edges of the original graph.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Suppose there is no Hamilton Cycle in $G$ but we can vistit all vertices in $G'$ via a trail, then I couldn't figure out why more unit weight edges would be include. There can be a small cycle in the trail, and the cost would still be n-2nW.

Comment: in an undirected graph, this problem is in P: you compute a minimum {s,t}-join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longest path problem can be reduced to this problem. Let $G = (V,E)$ be an instance of longest $s,t$-path problem. For each vertex $v \in V$ create two vertices, $v_{in}$ and $v_{out}$, and a directed edge with weight $-1$ from $v_{in}$ to $v_{out}$. For each edge $(u, v) \in E$, create an edge from $u_{out}$ to $v_{in}$ with weight $0$. Now each trial in this graph corresponds to a simple path in the graph $G$, and the edges with weight $-1$ count its length.